# Compiling an Octave mex file through Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, octave, mex

I just switched to Octave from Matlab and would like to continue to compile mex-files as a DLL through visual studio.

I have a project which creates a dll and exports the mexFunction as previously. I also include the mex.h file found in Octave but I have trouble linking.

Currently I get a linking error stating:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_mexPrintf referenced in function mexFunction
```

I understand why but I don't know what to include to resolve this issue.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Henrik

Comment: When you compile mex files for use with MATLAB you need to link them with libmx and libmex, I'd assume you're missing these, or similar, libraries that Octave ships.

Comment: @Praetorian. This is exactly the case. However, I have yet to figure out where these are located within the Octave framework.

Comment: You should try to first compile some example source file that Octave ships using the command line `mex` command, pass it the verbose (`-v`) switch and look at the names of the libraries being passed in the linker command.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me the libraries. However, I was trying to do a 64-bit compilation, which gave me other bugs. But, switching back solved the issue. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The files are found in:

C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\lib\octave\3.8.2

and I used liboctave.dll.a and liboctinterp.dll.a